# Protractor/Selenium get text of element

Tags: selenium, protractor

**HTML**

```
   <span class="catalog value">
    <sup class="dollar-symbol">$</sup> 
     2.06
    </span>
```

**CODE**

```
amountidentifier = 'span[class="catalog value"]';

element.all(by.css(amountidentifier))
            .filter((elem: any, index: any) => {
            return elem.getText().then((text: string) => {
                console.log("text is " + text);

            });
        })
```

I want to get the text value of 2.06. But console statement is not shown.

Comment: How this is  'amount/identifier'  a css selector? please specify the css selector and the output ur getting?

Comment: @Navarasu you are right, added the css selector. It is amountidentifier = 'span[class="catalog value"]';

Comment: what is your console statement?

Comment: Your css selector and script look right.  Try add a sleep for debug and check `span[class="catalog value"]` in DevTool manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `getText()` for `<span>`. Try to use this:

```
var somevariable = element(by.css('span[class="catalog value"]')).getAttribute('textContent');
console.log('text is' + somevariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector should be `span.catalog.value`. SPAN is the HTML tag and `.catalog` and `.value` are the two CSS classes that are applied to that tag.

Here are some CSS selector references to help you learn more.

[W3C CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)

[Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

[Taming Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)

Comment: If I don't use filter for elementall it works fine for me. browser.element.all(by.css('span.catalog.value')).then(function(items) {

            for(let item of items) {
                item.getText().then((text: string) => {
                        console.log('TEXT!! ' + text);
                        return text;
                })
            }
        });